# Does the jQuery UI Icon system have an "empty" icon - one with no image?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, icons

Sounds like a bit of a silly question but it'd be a nice feature.

Does the jQuery UI Icon system have an "empty" icon - one with no image?

Am I forced to do some custom styling on a ui-icon-empty and move the background to an area of the sprite that is off the chart?

Comment: Just a thought, why don't you make it background:none?

Comment: i think no but you can check here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: @Kerry - I created a ui-icon-empty class that does just that, but I was thinking it'd be nice if it came by default.  This is because the Button tool in 1.8 has a bug where if you null out the icon, it still has the spacing.  I'd like to have it stuck at the same width to avoid that problem which is why I needed the ui-icon-empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you look in the css file provided by jquery ui theme you will find a class named :

```
ui-icon-blank
```

you can use the same to have blank icons.

Thanks ...

TC

Answer (score 6):

I just ended up creating a `.ui-icon-empty { background:none }` and calling that via the button tool:

```
$(selector).button({icons:{primary: 'ui-icon-empty'}})
```

It worked, but seems wonky.  It'd be great if there was a ui-icon-empty in ui.base

Comment: I needed to do this to override the .ui-icon default:  `.ui-icon-none.ui-icon { background-image: none; }` (exactly like that, no spacing)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an anchor in a list and want to remove the icon add "data-icon='false'" to your list tag to remove the icon.

```
<li data-icon="false">
    <a href="#">Label</a>
</li>
```